# How to color cells in Datatable based on values of multiple cells?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have a dataframe like the one below, with one column for a large "Group" and another indicating the "Team" someone is on within that group, and additional columns indicating their expenditure in different time periods.

```
data <- data.frame("Team" = c("Alex", "Beth", "Andrew", "Bert"),
       "Group" = c("A","B","A","B"),
       "Spending_Q1" = c(1000, 500, 1500, 1000),
       "Spending_Q2" = c(500, 2000, 1000, 500))
```

Using the DT package, I would like to color the Spending_Q1 and Spending_Q2 columns based on their respective values (with a gradient: darker colors for higher values), but with a different color for each Team. I've been able to do most of this, with the same color gradient (e.g. shades of blue) applied to all values, but am not sure if it's possible to limit the shading to specific rows *and* columns. Can anyone advise?

I've consulted the RStudio [guide to data table styling](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html) but it doesn't have any examples for specifying shading for both specific rows and columns.

Thanks!

Comment: hi, I don't know if you can do that with `DT` but maybe the [`formattable`](https://www.littlemissdata.com/blog/prettytables) package can help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. The rendering does not work in RStudio, but it works in the browser.

```
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(
  "Team" = c("Alex", "Beth", "Andrew", "Bert"),
  "Group" = c("A","B","A","B"),
  "Spending_Q1" = c(1000, 500, 1500, 1000),
  "Spending_Q2" = c(500, 2000, 1000, 500),
  "Spending_Q3" = c(500, 1000, 1500, 1500)
)
columns <- c(3, 4, 5) # columns we want to colorize
nrows <- nrow(dat)

rowCallback <- c(
  "function(row, data, index){",
  sprintf("  var columns = [%s];", toString(columns)),
  "  var min = data[columns[0]];", 
  "  var max = data[columns[0]];",
  "  for(let i = 1; i < columns.length; i++){",
  "    min = Math.min(min, data[columns[i]]);",
  "    max = Math.max(max, data[columns[i]]);",
  "  }",
  sprintf("  var nrows = %d;", nrows),
  "  var h = index * 360/nrows;",
  "  for(let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){",
  "    var j = columns[i];",
  "    var l = 75 - 50*(data[j]-min)/(max-min);",
  "    var color = 'hsl(' + h + ', 100%, ' + l + '%)';",
  "    $('td:eq(' + j + ')', row).css('background-color', color);",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

datatable(
  dat, 
  options = list(
    rowCallback = JS(rowCallback),
    columnDefs = list(
      list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
    )
  )        
)
```

[image]